# Google Authentication via owin returns access denied

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, owin, google-authentication

I am using google owing middleware for authentication

The following is my middleware setup

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            //AuthenticationType = AuthServerConstants.PrimaryAuthenticationType
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive,
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
        }).UseExternalSignInCookie(AuthServerConstants.ExternalAuthenticationType);
```

The following is my google Middleware

```
var google = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = AppSettingHelpers.GetValue<string>(AppSettingConstants.GoogleAppId),
            ClientSecret = AppSettingHelpers.GetValue<string>(AppSettingConstants.GoogleAppSecret),
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = signInAsType,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive
        };
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(google);
```

I have enabled the Google+API in the google developer console

[image]

I am using Google Middleware version 2.1. My google authentication still returns `error=access_denied`

can anyone let me know what could have been missed out in this process.

**NOTE**
 My external authentication cookie middleware does not set the cookie yet in the browser.

Comment: Have you tried directly calling it without using GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions? that means, app.UseGoogleAuthentication(AppSettingHelpers.GetValue<string>(AppSettingConstants.GoogleAppId), AppSettingHelpers.GetValue<string>(AppSettingConstants.GoogleAppSecret))

Comment: Not yet, may be I will try that. The proper source code for v2.1 is not there even to debug. This code was working fine for me till 10 days, don't know what is wrong all of a sudden

Comment: Should I migrate to v3.0 for sure from now http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/07/02/changes-to-google-oauth-2-0-and-updates-in-google-middleware-for-3-0-0-rc-release.aspx

Comment: done the migration to version 3.0.0 for all OWIN dll's still the issue persists

Comment: That your calling them AppId and AppSecret makes me wonder if you're getting these values from the right place.  See https://console.developers.google.com/project/[project]/apiui/credential, "Client ID for web application"

Comment: @Tratcher: I am getting the values from the AppSettings. Actually the problem was that the IP Address was blocking somewhere in the corporate network. I tested in Amazon server and its working fine. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, April 20, 2014 the Open ID  was deprecated, because of that we can't use

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication();
```

instead, we have to create project using [Goolge Console](https://console.developers.google.com/). Then you need to update your code same as you did with 'ClientId' and 'ClientSecret'.

Your code should look like

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(AppSettingHelpers.GetValue<string>(AppSettingConstan‌​ts.GoogleAppId),     AppSettingHelpers.GetValue<string>(AppSettingConstants.GoogleAppSecret));
```

**Note that**: You should be careful when providing Redirect URIs when creating project on Google console. Because the Redirect URIs may look like

```
 http://YourDomain/signin-google 
LocalHost - https://YourLocalHost/signin-google
```

This works for me.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue lately. In my case I had to enable Google+ API on Google developer console. You can enable the Google+ API by first typing the name on  "Find product and services" search box and then by clicking on "Enable" button.